# IntelliJ IDEA find class in project jars

Tags: intellij-idea, jar

I've seen some posts on finding a class via searching jars in a directory and it caused me to think there must be a tool in IntelliJ IDEA to do this.  Anyone aware of such a tool and how to use it?

Comment: intellj can automatically decompile jar files, so you can search over the all .class files.

Comment: Technically since a jar file is just a zip file you can find out what classes are in a jar just buy in effect doing a  "zip -v zipfile" to show the .classes contained in the zip.  IntelliJ also has the ability to decompile .class files so for instance you can 'goto definition' of a class and IntelliJ will show you the decompiled code.  In the past (I believe) IntelliJ did the decompilation with a JAD plugin but currently uses a decompiler called fernflower.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the jar files are imported as project dependencies you can type `cmd + n` then search it.

[image]

Comment: I was about to post this as well, this is the best option, if the jars are imported as project dependencies.

Comment: Thank you so much - you just saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Upvote.. But please list "your" O/S when posting shortcuts. This is the "Go To Class" shortcut.  Here is cheat-sheet : https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf   for mac , it is the CMD-O.  (where CMD button on mac is the weird roundy-X button)

Answer (score 2):

The new key mappings for IntelliJ use double ⇧ (shift).  Tap shift twice to get to the search everywhere window then tab once to classes.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/searching-everywhere.html